# C Programming (Functions pointer casting)

Tags: c, function, pointers, casting

```
int eax = ((int(*)())("\xc3 <- This returns the value of the EAX register"))();
```

**How this works ? String is casted to function pointer**

Comment: not sure if it even does. If anything, then maybe `c3` in hexadecimal is the opcode of returning the EAX register or something like this. But really, a lot of context is missing.

Comment: Here's the original context: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5602143/544557

Comment: And here's a later version: https://gist.github.com/leegao/910993

Comment: Are literal strings still placed in executable memory nowadays? Tssk, tssk… It wouldn't cost anything to place them in non-executable memory, and the less memory is marked as executable, the better (even if it is already read-only)

Comment: @PascalCuoq Read the comments on the first link I posted.

Comment: @JimBalter Indeed. Faith in humanity restored.

Answer (score 12):

`c3` is the `RET` instruction. When an x86 machine jumps to this string interpreted as code, it will execute `RET` and therefore jump right back without having done anything (the rest of the string is therefore ignored). Since standard calling convention on x86 is to put your return value in `eax`, but the code didn't do anything before returning, whatever was already in `eax` will still be there, and in a position for the C code to interpret it as having been "returned".

This is highly dependent on your machine being x86 and that you're allowed to cast between data and function pointers (and execute the result) - a *very* system-specific hack. This is not standard compliant *or* portable C by any stretch!

(`\xXX` is C's escape syntax for inserting single nonreadable characters into strings via their ASCII code in hex, if you didn't know that part.)

Answer (score 5):

`0xc3` is the `ret` opcode in x86. The rest of the string is only there for flavor. All of the work is done by the calling convention, and the `cdecl` calling convention (the default one for the C language) says that a function that returns `int` returns it in `eax`.

Your function doesn't actually do *anything*, it just returns as soon as it's called, but any code that calls `int foo = eax()` is still going to expect it to have put its return value into the `eax` register, so it's going to copy the contents of the `eax` register into `foo`.